# Unable to match string value with the output from System.setproperty

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I use maven CLI cmd to provide the BROWSER value in real-time while execution

> mvn -DBROWSER=firefox install

and I use the below snippet to automatically fetch the BROWSER value as `firefox` from terminal cmd; but, when I try to match the condition with manual String value, `browser=="firefox"`, it fails to match and returns to else part.

```
String browser = System.getProperty("BROWSER");

    if(browser=="chrome")
    {
        System.out.println("CHROME initiated");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./libs/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browser=="firefox") {
        System.out.println("FIREFOX initiated");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./libs/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Skipped and CHROME initiated");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./libs/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

[image]
[image]

However, I want the test to move into `else if (browser=="firefox")` part matching `browser=="firefox"`. Is this due to the format issue; I have also used `.toString()` but it didnt work for me.

Comment: That is because you don't compare strings with == in Java; you have to use equals(). And for the record: if you dont know about such basics, you better spend some time studying those basics before getting into such kind of advanced topics.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat ; I use Javascript tats y confused in this :)